# Selection of objects on different layers

Tags: qgis, select

How could I select two different objects from two different layers using code or in the QGIS interface itself?

[image]

An example.
I have two elements in two different layers; that green dot, and the orange square, on another layer. What I want is to be able, geographically to be able to select them and to later associate them by some field. The problem is in that if I could make a union, but of course, that would refer to all the elements of the layers, and in this case, I want to choose them, some yes and others no, so try it a geographical mode.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works.

Comment: I don't know if the question is correct ,,, but trying, I couldn't try anything, because Qgis won't allow me ,,, I think, that's why I was asking

Comment: may be you could explain more about the two layers and how you would like to select them

Comment: ok ,,, let's see if I can describe it a little more; thanks Ian

Comment: Sorry, this is still unclear.

Comment: it's already solved